# recaptcha.rb not found in initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recaptcha

I am following [this](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/) link for captcha implementation. After including `gem "recaptcha", require: "recaptcha/rails"` in my `Gemfile` when I run bundle install at last, `recaptcha.rb` is not getting generated. How to fix it?

Comment: try to add it manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, just adding a gem to your Gemfile won’t cause any files to be generated. There is no reason to expect `config/initializers/recaptcha.rb` to exist after the steps you have described.

Some Rails gems include new Rails generators to create configuration files. For example, [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) implements `rails generate devise:install`. However, I see no mention of such a generator in the README for [reCAPTCHA](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/). So if you want to have a configuration file at `config/initializers/recaptcha.rb`, like [the example in reCAPTCHA’s README](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/#recaptchaconfigure), you should just create that file yourself using your text editor, copy and paste the example contents in, and modify it for your needs. This looks like the structure for that file:

```rb
Recaptcha.configure do |config|
  # configure whatever you need to here
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You should create it manually by yourself in the `config/initializers` folder as `recaptcha.rb`. In this file you can put your keys and other modifications.

```rb
Recaptcha.configure do |config|
  config.public_key  = 'Replace with your public key'
  config.private_key = 'Replace with your private key'
end
```